# In bash readline, how do I make the incremental search case insensitive

Tags: bash, readline

At the bash prompt, I can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> to perform incremental search of my command history.

However, the search is case sensitive: If I have a command `cat SomeFile.txt`, and I hit "*Ctrl-r somefile*", I get nothing.

Is there a way to make that search case-insensitive?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Short Answer:** No you can't get this feature in BASH at present because this feature hasn't been built yet into `vi or emacs mode`. As I commented above `completion-ignore-case` only applies to completion, not to `isearch`.

Comment: Kinda surprising this feature isn't built in to bash yet.

Answer (score -4):

see if you have a file called "inputrc" in either "~/.inputrc" or "/etc/inputrc" and add the line.

```
set completion-ignore-case on
```

Comment: `completion-ignore-case` only applies to completion, not to `isearch`

Comment: I think it still would apply. Because "ctrl-R" the reverse-search, uses the "readline" utility for matching strings. As stated in the documentation "If set to On, readline performs filename matching and completion in a case-insensitive fashion." I would assume it uses completion of some sort to come up with a match, so it should still work.

Comment: No, there is big difference between completion and search. Try it out yourself in your terminal.

Comment: Why isn't this answer deleted yet?